# Mongodb AsQueryable()

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am using mongoDB C# driver 2.4.0 , when I try to use LINQ I am getting error:

```
Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.Linq.IMongoQueryable`1<!!0> MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection`1<!!0>, MongoDB.Driver.AggregateOptions)'.
```

My context class snippet to get collection is:

```
 public IMongoCollection<SGProduct> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return Database.GetCollection<SGProduct>("SGProductRepository");
            }
        }
```

And the method I am using to extract data from mongo is:

```
public void GeHouseDetailByProduct(string catID)
        {
            var query =                 (from p in MongoContext.Products.AsQueryable()
                               join h in MongoContext.House.AsQueryable() on
                               p.HouseID equals h._id
                               where p.ProductCategoryID == catID
                               select h);     
        }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried omitting the second `AsQueryable()`?

Comment: Yes I just tried it, still getting same error.

Comment: Do `join's` work now with MongoDB? I was under the impression that they were not supported.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by downgrading the driver from 2.4 to 2.2. Still not sure why c# driver 2.4 doesn't support this.

Thanks